# How to configure multiple hot standbys in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I currently have a postgres server setup with a hot standby.  Is it possible to setup a second standby server?  The purpose of this copy would be to provide real-time reporting off the database, not be a true standby server.

I cannot find any information on configuring a second standby server, so I would like to know:

1. Is it possible?
2. If so, how to configure it in recovery.conf
3. If not, other suggestions for replicating for reporting purposes.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. I assume (based on you term "hot standby") that you are using streaming replication right now with your actual standby server.

For this you setup the master server with a pg_hba.conf allowing the slave to connect to the special database "replication". For the additional slave you need an additional entry (don't forget the reload)

```
# The standby server must connect with a user that has replication privileges.
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  host  replication     replication     192.168.0.20/32         md5
```

The user "replication" is created by using psql:

```
$ CREATE ROLE replication WITH REPLICATION PASSWORD 'password' LOGIN
```

The configuration on the master should be there (wal_level = hot_standby and probably an activated archiving).

On the reporting-slave you just need a full backup and a valid recovery.conf. If you use pg_basebackup it can create a recovery.conf for you (see the blog entry https://www.depesz.com/2012/02/03/waiting-for-9-2-pg_basebackup-from-slave/).
Don't forget hot_standby = on to use the slave for read-only-queries.

You also can use the "old" slave as master for the reporting-slave (cascading replication).

Answer (score 0):

An answer for documentation readers;

1. Sure
2. Read the documentation first. [Log-Shipping Standby Servers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html)
3. Also, read [Recovery Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-config.html) for recovery configuration.